# Asking about definitions of word "sugar" in biochemistry

Tags: biochemistry, carbohydrates

In a lecture about anabolic pathways of sugar, the lecturer was not clear when stating the name of a multiple sugar carrier & it sounded like "dolichol"so is it correct?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolichol

Comment: @xavier I'm not particularly looking forward to see this question tagged under [tag:biochemistry]. The tag wiki (excerpt) clearly states that the tag ought to be used if the post is about biochemical *processes* ;P

Comment: Apologies I was thinking of sugar transfer reactions in which dolichols take part in biochemistry, and I thought it was fitting

Comment: I'm no biochemist, but... aren't the *title* of the the post (definition of a "sugar"), and the post itself (is there a certain something called "dolichol"?), two *different* things? o_o

Comment: Maybe the title is slightly off, but I am sure OP is referring to anabolic pathways specifically sugar transfer reactions, in body text :)

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely correct!

> N-Linked oligosaccharides are initially synthesized as lipid-linked
>   precursors. The lipid component in this process is dolichol, *a
>   long-chain polyisoprenol of 14 to 24 isoprene units (17–21 units in
>   animals and 14–24 units in fungi and plants; isoprene units are C5
>   units with the carbon skeleton of isoprene* , which is linked to the
>   oligosaccharide precursor via a pyrophosphate bridge.

Dolichols apparently **anchor** the growing oligosaccharide to the endoplasmic reticulum membrane. These compounds have strong hydrophobic interactions with membrane lipids, anchoring the attached sugars to the membrane, where they participate in sugar-transfer reactions.

The pathway of dolichol-PP-oligosaccharide synthesis involves stepwise addition of monosaccharide units to the growing glycolipid by specific glycosyltransferases to form a common “core” structure:

[image]

*Dolichol pyrophosphate glycoside. The carbohydrate precursors of N-linked glycosides are synthesized as dolichol pyrophosphate glycosides. Dolichols are longchain polyisoprenols (n = 14–24) in which the α-isoprene unit is saturated.*

References

- Voet and Voet Biochemistry
- Lehninger Principles of Biochemistry